# Javascript date variable assignment

Tags: javascript, variables, date

```
var date1 = new Date();  
date1.setFullYear(2011, 6, 1);  

// 2011-07-01, ok  
console.log(date1);

// set date2 the same date as date1  
var date2 = date1;

// ...

// now I'm gonna set a new date for date2  
date2.setFullYear(2011, 9, 8);

// 2011-10-08, ok  
console.log(date2);

// 2011-10-08, wrong, expecting 2011-07-01  
// I didn't assign a new date to date1  
// WHY is date1 changed?  
console.log(date1);
```

Comment: Its looks like `date2` is being set as a pointer to what `date1` is pointing to.

Comment: why 2011-07-01, ok if you assign date1.setFullYear(2011, 6, 1);  is it not corect to be 2011-06-01 ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Date is object , so it is assigned as reference - simple approach is

```
date2 = new Date( date1 );
```

Answer (score 8):

When you do this:

```
date2=date1;
```

...you're not creating a *new* `Date` object, you're just pointing to the date object from two separate variables. There's only one object, so naturally any changes you make to it are apparent regardless of which variable you look through.

Let's throw some ASCII-art at it:

```
date1 = new Date();
```

That gives us:

```
+-------+
+ date1 +
+-------+                 +---------------+
| value |---------------->| a Date object |
+-------+                 +---------------+
```

Now when you do:

```
date2=date1;
```

We have

```
+-------+
+ date1 |
+-------+
| value |------+
+-------+      |          +---------------+
               +--------->| a Date object |
               |          +---------------+
+-------+      |
+ date2 |      |
+-------+      |
| value |------+
+-------+
```

The *value* of the `date1` and `date2` variables is a *reference* to the `Date` object, not a copy of it. (All objects work this way.) You can think of an *object reference* as like a memory address of where to find the object in memory. (What it *actually* is depends on the implementation.)

This is different from *primitives*, where the value of the variable actually contains the primitive's data, e.g.:

```
var n = 42;
```

Results in

```
+-----------+
+     n     |
+-----------+
| value: 42 |
+-----------+
```

(In *theory*. In fact, string "primitives" will behave as though that's true, but in reality probably are stored more like objects. Doesn't matter, strings are immutable and `==` and `===` for string *primitives* compares their content, so we can't really tell the difference and we can pretend that they're actually contained by the variable. [Just to really be confusing: JavaScript also has `Number` and `String` **objects**, which behave like objects.])

---

Re your question below:

> In the interim, what is the most efficient way to create a second javascript object identical to a preexisting one?

There is no generic "clone" operation for JavaScript objects, so the answer varies by object. Some objects you don't need to clone, because they're immutable (can't be changed) and so don't need cloning (`String` objects, for instance).

To clone a *date*, it's easy:

```
date2 = new Date(date1);
```

Or the *slightly* more efficient:

```
date2 = new Date(+date1);
```

(Because the `+` tells the `date1` object to convert itself to a number, and then the `Date` constructor uses that number. Without it, the `date1` object would be asked to convert itself to a string, and then the `Date` constructor would parse that string. Still works, but going via the number is a micro- and almost certainly premature optimization — and one that might interfere with any hidden optimization an engine might want to use. So I'd just go with `date2 = new Date(date1);`.)

Comment: Just passing the date directly should be faster, it will call `ToPrimitive` either way so the `+` conversion is redundant. Not that it matters :P

Comment: @Esailija: You'd think that, wouldn't you? Except that the `Date` constructor [calls `ToPrimitive` with no hint](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2). `ToPrimitive` [calls `[[DefaultValue]]` passing on the lack-of-hint](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1), and [the default hint for `Date`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.8) (unlike everything else) is `String`, not `Number`. Of course, an implementation would be free to optimize... And as you say, not that it matters.

Answer (score 2):

Both date variables are just references to the same date object in memory. So you need `date2` to be a *clone* of `date1`. Change:

```
var date2 = date1;
```

to this:

```
var date2 = new Date(date1.getTime());
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript uses pass by reference for Dates* (as well as all non-primitives -- `var o = {}; var j = o; j.foo = 1; console.log(o.foo); //1`. On the other hand, for Numbers, Strings, and Booleans `var o = 0; var j = o; j++; console.log(j); // 0`), so that is expected behavior.

If you need to copy a date you can always

```
var date2 = new Date( date1.getTime() );
```

* Please see comments to understand why this is not entirely correct.

Comment: It's not really pass by reference. It's pass by value where the value is the reference. If it were pass by reference, changing the reference would change the object: `a={}; b=a; b=null;` In a pass by reference evaluation model, `a===null` should be true, since `b` *is* `a` and we set `b` to `null`.

Comment: @davin That is a subtlety I had not known about.

Comment: Up vote. Very helpful. One detail however. If `date2` has already been allocated, then there is no need for the use of `new`. The assignment would be accomplished by: `date2.setTime(date1.valueOf());`.

Answer (score 1):

`date2` It's a reference to `date1`.

To achieve the expected results, do the following:

```
var date1 = new Date();
date1.setFullYear(2011, 6, 1); 

var date2 = new Date();
date2.setTime(date1.valueOf());
```

Answer (score 1):

The **solution** is to create a second date that uses the same internal millisecond value, copied from the first:

```
var date1 = new Date();
var date2 = new Date(date1.getTime());
```

*Now* you've got two distinct date instances that you can manipulate independently of one another.

```
var date1 = new Date();
alert(date1); // Sat May 26 2012 11:26:16 GMT-0400 (EDT)
var date2 = new Date(date1.getTime());
date2.setMinutes(date2.getMinutes()+10);
alert(date1); // Sat May 26 2012 11:26:16 GMT-0400 (EDT)
alert(date2); // Sat May 26 2012 11:36:16 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

More reading: [Date – MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: It appears you can clone date object just by passing it directly to date constructor

Answer (score 1):

Variation of [@SergeS's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6609625), but Date() objects in js coerce to number, so you don't need getTime():

```
// general case
var dateValueCopy = new Date(date1);
```

And restated with OP variable names:

```
var date2 = new Date(date1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a copy of `date1`, currently `date1` and `date2` refer to the same date object.

```
var date2 = new Date(date1.valueOf());
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
date1 = new Date();  // <-- creates a new Date object
date2 = date1;       // <-- date2 gets passed a reference to the date1 object
                     //     making them effectively the same
```

You create a Date object on the first line, but the second line does *not* create another Date object, it only points or references the Date object that was already created. This is a common feature in many object oriented programming languages.