# Changing the value of a copy (Date variable) also changes the value of the original (JS)

Tags: javascript, variables, copy

I have a date-variable that I want to use as a basis to work with it:

```
var Uhrzeit = new Date();
```

Now I want to copy this basis in a new variable to work with it, for this, I just created a new variable and assigned the value of the first.

```
var u = Uhrzeit
```

I have this little code-snippet:

```
var Uhrzeit = new Date();
Uhrzeit.setMinutes(0);
Uhrzeit.setSeconds(0);
console.log("Uhrzeit: " + Uhrzeit);
Uhrzeit.setSeconds(61);
console.log("Uhrzeit: " + Uhrzeit)
var u = Uhrzeit;
console.log("u: " + u);
u.setSeconds(200);
console.log("u: " + u);
console.log("Uhrzeit: " + Uhrzeit)
```

It generates the following output:

```
Uhrzeit: Sun Apr 05 2020 15:00:00 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)
Uhrzeit: Sun Apr 05 2020 15:01:01 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)
u: Sun Apr 05 2020 15:01:01 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)'
u: Sun Apr 05 2020 15:04:20 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)
Uhrzeit: Sun Apr 05 2020 15:04:20 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)
```

Now there is the following problem: u, in the end, has a value with 4 Min and 20Sec. Uhrzeit has the same value althouhgt it should have the value of 1Min and 1Sec. Why does Uhrzeit have the same value as u when I change the value of u?

I hope this is no duplicate, I only found posts about this issue in other languages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript date variable assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609574/javascript-date-variable-assignment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Please note:

`var Uhrzeit = new Date();` Creates a new Date Instance which is an object.

The moment you assign `var u = Uhrzeit`, this in javascript means that u refers to the same object of date that `Uhrzeit` refers to.

So variables for objects holds the reference in memory where the object is stored. And by assigned a variable that references an object is simply going to pass that reference to the new variable.

The moment you change either `u` or `Uhrzeit` they both reference the same object and they both change the same object.

You must do this instead:

`var u = new Date(Uhrzeit);` this will create `u` with the value of `Uhrzeit`. But they both will now reference different objects in memory.