# Wrong increment of dates in a while statement

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i'm working on a code that increments a date of an object in a while statement and put in an array at every iteration, i can't understand why but when i print the array on the console, the incremented date is alwais on the last day incremented, the code is here:

```
 while (Difference_In_Days > 1) {

            var assTemp = new assenza()
            Difference_In_Days = date2.getDate() - date1.getDate();
            assTemp.data_ass = date1
            assTemp.id_ass = 0
            assTemp.motivo = "" + motivo
            assTemp.dipendente = this.dipendente
            this.assArr.push(assTemp)
            var assTemp = new assenza()
            date1.setDate(date1.getDate() + 1)
        }
```

and the result of the console.log(JSON.stringify(this.assArr)):

> [
> {
> "id_ass":0,
> "data_ass":"2021-10-15T00:00:00.000Z",
> "motivo":"salute",
> "dipendente":{}
> },

> {
> "id_ass":0,
> "data_ass":"2021-10-15T00:00:00.000Z",
> "motivo":"salute",
> "dipendente":{}
> },

> {
> "id_ass":0,
> "data_ass":"2021-10-15T00:00:00.000Z",
> "motivo":"salute",
> "dipendente":{}
> }
> ]

as you can see the data_ass(the dates) are always the same, why?
if i put a console.log of date1 in the while it shows me a correct increment day by day trough the iterations. thanks for your help

Comment: You have placed the same date object everywhere, then increment it, so the 1 object you have is incremented 3 times, and shown 3 times in your output. You need to use a separate copy of the date object. Looking at your code this means you need to create a new `date3` **inside** of the loop and use that instead of `assTemp.data_ass = date1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript date variable assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609574/javascript-date-variable-assignment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to copy date1 to assTemp.data_ass, rather than assigning the reference, by changing the line

```
assTemp.data_ass = date1
```

to

```
assTemp.data_ass = new Date(date1);
```

Otherwise each instance of assTemp will hold the same value for data_ass, namely the last value.