# setTime is overriding a react state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

Check this out, for some reason when I setState with a date, and then create a new variable like newD = startDate and apply newD.setTime() it is overriding the original state variable even though Im not calling setState()

I cant seem to understand how to initialize a new variable.

PS timezone variable is set to "America/New_York" so its currently -04:00

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import momentt from 'moment-timezone';


const myComponent = () => {


const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(Oct 30 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time))


useEffect(() => {



console.log("startDate", startDate.toISOString())
//2022-10-30T06:00:00.000Z

const newD = startDate
    
    const applyOffset = newD.setTime(newD.getTime() - newD.getTimezoneOffset() * 60_000);
      const actualTime = new Date(applyOffset).toISOString().replace("Z", "")
      const toTz = momentt.tz(actualTime, timezone).format()
    const getUTCTime = momentt.utc(toTz).format()

    console.log("startDate", startDate.toISOString())
//2022-10-30T00:00:00.000Z <---- WHy is this changing without calling setStartDate()?
})

return (
<div>



</div>
)
}
```

Comment: Dates are just objects, so you're mutating all references to it, including the reference stored in state. You'll need to make a copy of it `const newD = new Date(startDate);`

Comment: duplicate: [Javascript date variable assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609574/javascript-date-variable-assignment)

Comment: "Palms forehead"